# How to make first rootLevelNode to open by default

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using tree compone i,e (Tree with partially loaded data).Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kdepalderex?file=app%2Ftree-loadmore-example.html) example

I want first  rootLevelNode to be openend by default.
Something like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your component file put this :

```
  onTreeLoad(tree): void {
    setTimeout(function(){  
        const firstNode = tree.treeModel.getFirstRoot();
        if(firstNode != undefined) {
            firstNode.expand();
        }
    }, 200);
}
```

In your template file put this :

```
 <mat-tree-node   #tree *ngIf = "nodes" (initialized)="onTreeLoad($event)" [options]="options" [focused]="true" [nodes]="nodes">
```

Comment: Getting this error `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-tree-node'.`

Comment: Remove options from there and check

Comment: Now this error `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'focused' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-tree-node'.`

Comment: remove focused also

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'nodes' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-tree-node'.` now this error.

Comment: <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node"  (initialized)="onTreeLoad($event)"matTreeNodePadding>

Comment: I have tried this also no errors and no result too.